# Why adding a layer of transpose_convolution to the decoder of a Variational encoder would lead to a shape not similar to the original one?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution, autoencoder

I'm trying to toy around with VAE's then tried to add some extra convolutional layer on the encoder and a trnaspose_convolutional to the decoder. The extra one in the convolutional works fine since it still ends up as the same compressed shaped; however, the transpose_convolutional layer in the decoder ends up with a different shape. May I ask for some explanation and perhaps some way to reshape this?

```
#encoder
latent_dim = 2

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()

Model: "encoder"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_19 (InputLayer)           [(None, 28, 28, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 14, 32)   320         input_19[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 7, 7, 64)     18496       conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 4, 4, 128)    73856       conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)             (None, 2048)         0           conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)                (None, 16)           32784       flatten_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_mean (Dense)                  (None, 2)            34          dense_18[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_log_var (Dense)               (None, 2)            34          dense_18[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sampling_3 (Sampling)           (None, 2)            0           z_mean[0][0]                     
                                                                 z_log_var[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 125,524
Trainable params: 125,524
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()

Model: "decoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_23 (InputLayer)        [(None, 2)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 3136)              9408      
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_18 (Reshape)         (None, 7, 7, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_59 (Conv2DT (None, 14, 14, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_60 (Conv2DT (None, 28, 28, 64)        73792     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_61 (Conv2DT (None, 56, 56, 32)        18464     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_62 (Conv2DT (None, 56, 56, 1)         289       
=================================================================
Total params: 175,809
Trainable params: 175,809
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---